# Prolog parsing and output

Tags: prolog

I have the following predicates in my database, which I successfully parsed from input:

```
19 ?- listing(element1).
:- dynamic element1/2.

element1('El1', [20]).
element1('El2', [25]).
element1('El3', [30]).
```

Now, given an appropriate query like 'List all elements' how do I output them nicely, like:

```
'El1, El2, El3 have values 20, 25, 30 respectively'  ?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SWI-Prolog supports calling user specified predicates by means of the ~@ [format specifier](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=format/2). So, if you write a predicate like

```
out_comma_sep_list(L) :- atomic_list_concat(L, ' ,', T), write(T).
```

you can do

```
report :-
  findall(A-B, element1(A, B), L), pairs_keys_values(L, As, Bs),
  format('~@ have values ~@ respectively', 
      [out_comma_sep_list(As), out_comma_sep_list(Bs)]).
```

Comment: But, won't findall additionally output L = [...] to the screen? I would like to suppress that somehow.

Comment: findall(A, element(A,B), L), write(L) returns me: L = ['El1', 'El2', 'El3'] \n [El1, El2, El2], which messes with my program. How do I eliminate this L output?

Comment: you should use `?- report.`